# Thread.Sleep not working!

Tags: c#, thread-safety

consider the following code that is executed in every instantiation of a certain class:

```
private void StartUpdateThread()
{
    runUpdateThread = true;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateUsages));
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
    thread.Start();
}

public void UpdateUsages()
{
    DateTime updateDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    while (runUpdateThread)
    {
        if (updateDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            _cpuUsage.Add(DateTime.Now, GetCPUUsage());

            if (_cpuUsage.Count == 61)
                _cpuUsage.Remove(_cpuUsage.ElementAt(0).Key);

            _ramUsage.Add(DateTime.Now, GetRamUsage());

            if (_ramUsage.Count == 61)
                _ramUsage.Remove(_ramUsage.ElementAt(0).Key);

            updateDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(15000);
    }
}
```

After adding 2 or 3 values to each Dictionary it throws "an element with the same key already exists in the dictionary". This should be impossible since i'm doing Sleep after each loop.
I've tried, unsuccessfully, to prevent this problem by adding the updateDateTime variable.

I'm running out of ideas. Can anyone help me or explain me how this can happen?

Thanks

Comment: On another note, your DateTime.Now calls will potentially return different times. You want to call it once, save the value in a variable, and then reuse that, at least within your `while` loop.

Comment: To get good answers, strive to post good questions. Please answer the following questions, either through text or by expanding on your example code: Are you accessing the data structures from other threads? If yes, what kind of access, read-only or read/write? How is "_cpuUsage" and "_ramUsage" defined? Are you starting multiple such threads or just one?

Comment: Considering that, then, how can it be possible to get that exception on differente loops?

Comment: Considering what? "different loops"? Are you running that code on multiple threads?

Comment: 1. I'm reading the _cpuUsage and _ramUsage from other threads.. the writing is only done on that while loop.

Comment: Only one thread is initialized

Comment: Are the dictionaries shared between multiple threads, as @Jon is asking? ie. "static"?

Comment: And your "only one thread is initialized" seems to be contrary to your claim that it is "executed in every instantiation of a certain class"

Comment: @tekknoplast: You shouldn't be reading and writing from a dictionary from multiple threads in the first place, without any locking. If you're using .NET 4, you should consider some of the concurrent collections - but again, I don't think a dictionary is really appropriate anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are either `_cpuUsage` or `_ramUsage` static by any chance? Or perhaps you've assigned the same value to both of them? If you could give us a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, it would make things a lot clearer.

On a side note, you seem to be hoping that your usage of `ElementAt(0)` will remove the earliest entry from the dictionary, but there's no guarantee of that.

From what you're doing, it *looks* like you'd be better off with a `LinkedList<Tuple<DateTime, long>>` or similar.

Comment: If the types are dictionaries, no other writing is done, would he see that type of error with that code, broken as it may be, but still?

Comment: @Lasse: If there are multiple threads accessing the same dictionary (if the variables are static and there are multiple instances) then it could explain things. Seeing more code would definitely help.

Comment: Yeah, if multiple threads are writing, he might very well either try duplicate keys, or he might just be corrupting the state beyond all hope.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice, "on every instance".

Comment: He needs locking if those dictionaries are shared, no way around it.

Comment: @Lasse: I strongly suspect the dictionaries aren't really *meant* to be shared, but they might be accidentally static.

Comment: You were right.. I was starting several UpdateUsages Threads. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain? "On a side note, you seem to be hoping that your usage of ElementAt(0) will remove the earliest entry from the dictionary, but there's no guarantee of that."

Comment: @tekknoplast: Dictionaries are inherently unordered. There's no guarantee that if you iterate over them, you'll get the entries in the order in which you added them.